# Set Value of Telerik RadGrid Using JavaScript from aspx page and retrive it on code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am Setting a RadNumeric Text box Value Using JavaScript from Aspx page. But when i use that value in the .CS page it is showing the old value. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way of setting the value fromjavascript so that it can be get via code behind.
Check http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/input/rad-numericinput-box-not-retain-client-side-set-values.aspx

Comment: Thanks For your quick reply. I am able to set value of Telerik RadText box. My problem is when i want that Value in CS page, then it show as 0. Can you help on this?